# sending a notification to my email when a time gets over 2:00 hours

Tags: google-apps-script

i work in shipping and i have to keep track of how long each truck is here. i have a spreadsheet set up with the time truck arrives and departs (this information is put in by our security team) i have a formula set to tell how long the truck was here and conditional formatting to show up red color after the time hit 2 Hours i'm wanting to set it up so i get an email only when a time goes over 2 Hours.
can you help me with this?

i have tired scrips and i cant get it to work right for some reason

thanks,
Matt

Comment: Welcome, please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit trickier than I thought at first because duration format provide a fraction day.  So I played around with switching the formatting before and after getting data so that I could get the actual fractional values.  So  all of the time columns have duration formatting not dates

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet ID");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("TimeSheet");
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var drg=sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var mrg=sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var mA=mrg.getValues();
  var dA=drg.getValues();
  var fA=rg.getNumberFormats();
  rg.setNumberFormat("0.####################");
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  rg.setNumberFormats(fA);
  var now=new Date();
  Logger.log(now);
  var daystart=new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate()).valueOf();
  var time=(now.valueOf()-daystart)/86400000;//converted to fraction of a day
  Logger.log(time);
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][5]) {
      var start=vA[i][0];
      dA[i][0]=time-start;
      mA[i][0]=time-start>2/24?"Email":"No Email";
    }
  }
  drg.setNumberFormat("0.####################");
  drg.setValues(dA);
  drg.setNumberFormat("hh:mm:ss");  
  mrg.setValues(mA);
  var msg=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(mA[i][0]=="Email" && !vA[i][5]) {
      msg.push(vA[i][3]);
    }
  }
  if(msg) {
    var recipient="your email";
    var subject="Trucks with durations greater than 2 hours";
    var body=Utilities.formatString('Trucks in the following locations: %s have been here for 2 hours or more.',msg.join(','));
    //GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);//email disabled
    var html=Utilities.formatString('recipient: %s<br />subject: %s<br />body: %s',recipient,subject,body);
    var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Trucks longer than two hours");
  }
}
```

This is the spreadsheet.  Columns 1,2 and 6 are setup with duration formatting

[image]

I disabled the Gmail line and used the dialog for testing.  You'll probably want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

From the code below, you can run the function `createTrigger` which will create an onEdit trigger [1] to run the function `sendEmail` when you edit the sheet. If the edited cell is in column D (you can set the column) and it turns to red by conditional formatting (comparing by the code color [2]) , it will use GmailApp [3] class to send an email.

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  var redCol = 4; //D column for durations
  var editedCell = e.range;
  var col = editedCell.getColumn();

  //Red color code, taken from a cell with red background in this case cell D2
  //You can replace this for the code string when you know it, default red is '#ff0000' 
  var cellColor =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ehUnxIraQI2ZWA_dLOt78Y4_c9k7zsQf1eiJiI9RMLk").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(2, redCol).getBackground();

  if(col == redCol) {
    var editedCellColor = editedCell.getBackground();
    if(editedCellColor == cellColor){
      Logger.log(cellColor)
      //Will send email when a cell in D column turns red
      GmailApp.sendEmail("email@example.com", "Subject: It has passed 2 hours", "Message body:" + cellColor);
    }
  }
}

function createTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[SPREADSHEET-ID]");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onEdit()
  .create();  
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body